# Loading state updates before onCompleted executes causes flash of content

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I currently have this mutation in my React component:

```
import { useNavigate } from '@remix-run/react'
...

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { redirectTo } = useNavigate();
  ...

  const [mutateFunction, { loading }] = useMutation(SOME_MUTATION, {
    onCompleted: () => {
      redirectTo('/foo')
    },
  });

  ...
}
```

When the mutation completes, the `loading` state changes, forcing a re-render on the react component before the `onCompleted` callback is executed.
This is causing a flash of content to appear on the page before the page is redirected. Is there any way to re-direct whilst the loading spinner is still showing, hence avoiding the flash on page content?

Comment: Not an expert on that tool, but seems like you could use an useEffect to detect the loading going to false and do the redirect there, before the onComplete is ran.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a separate state variable to track the loading state since you have a race condition between your `useMutation` `loading` state getting updated and your `onCompleted` handler. (I'm almost inclined to see this as a bug in apollo-client but that's a matter of opinion)

```
import { useNavigate } from '@remix-run/react'
import { useState } from 'react'
...

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { redirectTo } = useNavigate();
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);
  ...

  const [mutateFunction] = useMutation(SOME_MUTATION, {
    onCompleted: () => {
      redirectTo('/foo');
      setLoading(false);
    },
  });

  ...
  …function that invokes the mutation {
    setLoading(true);
    mutateFunction();
  }
}
```